# Analog sensor signal isolation for ADC/DAQ

Tags: sensor, isolation, ground-loop, daq

I am looking for the simplest way of sampling an analog sensor signal in an existing system while avoiding ground loops (say 20kHz maximum frequency). The sensor is a 5V supply with 0-5V return signal. I only need to sample the signal in a DAQ, but attaching to the sensor ground is causing ground loops. I can use the 5V supply if necessary to power an amplifier, but can alternately provide power from the DAQ side.

I believe an analog isolator is what I need, and that a single package would do the full job, but searching for the right component is finding amplifiers that require symmetric voltage supplies on both sides for example. What is the simplest solution for this application that is within say USD 10.00?

I have need for a high speed digital isolation and low speed analog, but high speed analog would just be more universal if possible.

Spec:

- 0-20 kHz
- 0-5 V
- 0.2 % linearity

All DAQ grounds are linked.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmh3yY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Have you considered using a micro on the sensor side and communicating the readings via optocouplers to the other side?  A digital isolator vs analog isolator?

Comment: What is the difference in potential between the two grounds - what ground circulating currents are there?

Comment: Can you incude a diagram ?

Comment: "require symmetric voltage supplies" You mean accepts the same voltage on both sides? Why is this required? Or even a problem finding? i have trouble NOT finding one that does that and if I could not, it is not really a deal breaker and can be worked around easily by adding a converter. Example: HCPL-7800

Comment: On the digital, I want a little as possible near the sensor so having conditioning, ADC etc. though it's an interesting idea.
The grounds are nominally at the same potential but there is a lot of electrical noise in the systems and I need to access multiple arms of a grounded system.
Symmetric voltages meaning say +- 10V supply as with some OpAmps.

Comment: So you need bipolar supplies on both sides? I would not count on being able to find that. Better off biasing the iso amp with -V and +V on a bipolar supply and using 0V as a signal reference. It is isolated after all so it doesn't care. But this runs contrary to your 5V sensor statement so I still do not see why you need bipolar.

Comment: Doesn't your DAQ provide a differential input? What is your DAQ (link)? Why not use two wires and measure differentially? I think you are at the point now where you definitely need to add a circuit of some sort. There are two many ambiguities to cover it with words. What does high-speed analogue actually mean in terms of requirements: speed, accuracy etc..

Comment: I don't *need* bipolar, it is all I could find for now. Accuracy requirements are added. Circuit diagram added. differential inputs might be in use but the grounds are all common.

Comment: @Andyaka I have provided more detail and everyone seems to have gone AWOL.

Comment: If your DAQ has locally grounded differential inputs then it's problematic. This is not how proper engineered DAQs are designed.

Comment: Why is that so complicated? I have been thinking about an isolator is a relatively simply components that takes an input voltage across one pair of terminals and generates that voltage differential with respect to a given ground.

Comment: @Andyaka that comment above was for you.

Comment: It's only complicated if you didn't realize that a fully differential DAQ input can do what you require without the cost and performance degradation of an analogue isolator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107298/discussion-between-j-collins-and-andy-aka).

Comment: I haven't got much time so don't expect quick answers.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have no

1) accuracy requirements,

2) no dynamic range requirements

3) no linearity requirements

I'd just use the sensor output to drive an LED; if you have linearity needs or want to avoid the deadband of an LED, then use a voltage-to-converter circuit to drive the LED.

Then couple the photons to a photodiode into a TIA at the DAQ.

Certainly less than $10.

Or just use heavy copper braid to tie the DAQ gnd to the sensor gnd. Much cheaper.

Comment: Dual photodiode, shared LED feedback optos also work if you need linearity. Like the HCNR200 and HCNR201. Read datasheet for application schematics. It's a little "roll your own circuit".

Comment: Accuracy, dynamic range and linearity I think are now addressed. Why is optical superior to electrical? Can't use a direct link for the ground loops.